# React element type cannot be coerced to 'string'

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, flowtype

I am trying to align icon in Button component. Passing **iconAlign** prop if it is right the icon will render first and text will later if left then vice versa. But I am getting this error by flow

```
React element `Icon`:  'object type'. See ./tmp/flow/flowlib_16523b66/react.js:159. This type cannot be coerced to 'string'.
```

Here is my component

```
<ButtonInner>
  {
    iconAlign === 'right' ? `${text} ${icon && <Icon color={iconColor} />}` :
      `${icon && <Icon color={iconColor} />} ${text}`
  }
</ButtonInner>
```

Am I missing something? Any better alternative please?

Comment: you cannot use `<Icon> ` inside a string literal, it tries to coerce the Object to a string but it has a special toString() that react catches and throws. refactor it to deal with the text separately. `iconAlign === 'right' ? ({text} <Icon />) : (<Icon /> {text})` - though you can solve the positioning based around CSS and not adjust order of items.

Comment: Yes I get that. Thanks @DimitarChristoff I found solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should not have used the string literals to render my react component. I just wrapped it in a **div** and that worked

```
<ButtonInner>
  {
    iconAlign === 'right' ?
      <div>{text} {icon && <Icon color={iconColor} /></div> :
      <div>{icon && <Icon color={iconColor} />} {text}</div>
  }
</ButtonInner>
```

This article helped https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Answer (score 1):

string literals finally convert everything to string. component's `toString` is tracked by react and it throws error when `toString` is called on a component. You can write the code as follows to achieve the same:

```
iconAlign === 'right' ? (
  <Fragment> `${text} ` icon && <Icon color={iconColor} /> </Fragment>) : (
  <Fragment> icon && <Icon color={iconColor} /> {` ${text}`} </Fragment>
)
```

If your are using react 16.2, you can user `Fragment` to wrap the children. You can of course go old school and add a `div` instead but that generates a lot of non-semantic divs in the generated html.

More about `Fragments` here : https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Comment: What if I have to pass the children between text and icon?

Comment: Pleasure @sudheersingh